# Mysql Connection Error from 1.1.1 to 1.2.1

Tags: playframework

I upgraded from 1.1.1 to 1.2.1 and I seem to be getting the following exception when it attempts to connect to MySQL:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343)
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
```

I've confirmed that MySQL is indeed running and seems to be working fine.  The following is the line from my application.conf file (with user/pass/db replaced):

db=mysql:username:password@databasename

I also tried using the full JDBC configuration.  Did I miss something?  This worked just fine in 1.1.1.  I'm running MySQL 5.1.41.

Thanks.

Comment: I use this syntax with Siena + Play 1.2.1 and the mysql connector works. So I would say that there might be a problem on your MySQL but I can imagine that you already tested everything about it!

Comment: Nothing has changed with MySQL.  It's still powering a couple other non-Play-related web sites just fine.  I have a Ruby on Rails app running on the same box and it's working fine.  This is a newly created site using the "play new" command.  Just modified the config for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

As an update - it was just a configuration issue.  I just uncommented out the "db=mysql:..." line in the application.conf file.  What I should have done is uncomment it and change it to:

dev.db=mysql:username:password@databasename

Comment: It stopped giving me the "Connection refused" error but within minutes started giving me a "no datasource" configuration error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clean tmp folder? play clean command should solve the problem.

Comment: Not only did I try this I also removed the folder completely.  I recreated with the "play new" command and ALL I did was change the application.conf file and uncommented the mysql "db=" line and updated the user/pass/database_name.  I restarted with the "play run" command and I'm still getting the "Connection refused" error.  I updated Mysql using an "apt-get upgrade mysql-server" to make sure I had the latest version.